# if statement passed but else statement is also executed - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, if-statement, authentication

I have a login system that loops through an array of objects to fetch and compare username and password entered by the user in the login page. I have issued an if statement to check if user credentials are correct. The problem am having is that the system shows the else statement even when the if statement has passed or the user credentials are correct.

Please see the full demo in the link below;

https://jsfiddle.net/dej5sr9z/

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Ayub Technologies"> 
  <meta name="author" content="Verai Bosobori" />  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"> 
  <meta name="description" content="">  
  <title>Lycan CREATIONS | Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
        
    <section>
        <div class="form_div">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div style="text-align:left; color:red; font-weight:bold;" id="error"></div>
        <div style="text-align:left; color:green; font-weight:bold;" id="success"></div>
        <br>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="">                
                </div> <br>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <label for="">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="passwd"   placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="form_input">
                    <p style="text-align:left; color:blue;"><a href="paswdReset.html">Forgot Password?</a></p>              
                </div>
                <div class="form_submit">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="getInfo()">Submit</button>               
                </div>
            </form>     
        </div>  
    </section>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Beolow is the JavaCript Code

```
var objPeople =[
        {
            username: "verai",
            passwd: "lycan"
        },
        {
            username: "ayub",
            passwd: "metah"
        },
        {
            username: "chris",
            passwd: "forever"
        }
]

function getInfo(){     
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var passwd = document.getElementById("passwd").value;
    var error = document.getElementById("error").innerHTML;
    
    if (username != '' || passwd != ''){        
        for(i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++){
            if(username == objPeople[i].username && passwd == objPeople[i].passwd){
                document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "Hello " + username + "!! You are successfully logged in!!!";
                console.log(username + " is logged in!!!");
                setTimeout(function(){           
                    document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("passwd").value = "";
                },5000);
            }else{
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = " Incorrect Username or Password. Please try again!";      
                setTimeout(function(){           
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("passwd").value = "";
                },2000);
                }
        }
    }else{
        // console.log("Your username is " + username + " and your password is " + passwd );
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "All fields required, please try again!";
        setTimeout(function(){           
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("username").value = "";
                document.getElementById("passwd").value = "";                                   
            },2000);
    }
}
```

I will appreciate if someone points out what am not doing right, thanks.

Comment: Because you only should run the code if none match. You run the code as soon as one fails.

Comment: `if (username != '' || passwd != ''){` Don't you want `if (username != '' && passwd != ''){`

Comment: You're checking to make sure the input matches all the users. You need to replace the for loop with a way to lookup a user, then only check the password for that one user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a correct combination has been entered, the for-loop goes into the `if`-part **once for the matching user**, but **also** it goes into the `else`-part **for all other non-matching users**. There is nothing in place to prevent that from happening.

You need to determine who is the one matching person *if any*, and then proceed with that result (which is either a user object, or `undefined`).

You can do so with [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), using code like this:

```
var matchingUser = objPeople.find(p => username === p.username && passwd === p.passwd);
if (matchingUser) {
   // ...
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Side note - I used the "triple equal sign", which does an **exact** comparison between objects without any type conversions that could get in the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Answer - issue  fixed. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/ewpx14dk/